# Jquery Responsive Image Grid

Tags: jquery, image, grid

http://ozan.io/collage/

In the above link there is a responsive image grid! There, on mouseover on each image there is a caption displayed! That is not a div but I think it's a javascript data-caption function! I dont want that!

I want something like this   http://themes.themepunch.com/?theme=megafoliopro_jq

On mouseover a div will be displayed covering each image in which i can keep options like "delete", "insert caption", etc.

How to do this???? Anyone???

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a `div` inside of a `div` that gets displayed when you hover over it.

```
<div class="outterDiv">
    <p> put some content here</p>
    <div class="innerDiv" style="display:none; width:100%; height:100%;">put options here</div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
<script>
    $('.outterDiv').hover(function(){
        $('.innerDiv').toggle();
    },
    function(){
        $('.innerDiv').toggle();
    });
</script>
```

This will show the inner div when you hover over the outer div and hide it when you mouse leaves the outer div.

Comment: oops forgot, you have to put the js inside $(document).ready(). Try this http://jsfiddle.net/DBMT4/